# Scikit-learn SVM: get reference to a function computing the kernel?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I'm using scikit-learn to do some basic SVM classification. I have the result of running sklearn.svm.fit on my data,

```
skObject = clf.fit(X,y)
```

and I get an object with some helpful attributes such as the coefficients of the dual formulation in `skObject.dual_coef_`.

My question is: **how can I get python-level access to the kernel used by scikit learn?** Is this an attribute of `skObject` that is not easy to tell by its name? Specifically, I want a fast (C-level) function I can use for computing the margin of a new datapoint.

Here is what I have tried

```
>>> skObject.kernel
'rbf'
```

Just a string

```
>>> skObject._compute_kernel
<bound method SVC._compute_kernel of SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, 
class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, degree=3, gamma=0.0, kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, 
probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)>
>>> skObject._compute_kernel(data[0], data[1])
... TypeError: _compute_kernel() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
>>> help(skObject._compute_kernel)
_compute_kernel(self, X) method of sklearn.svm.classes.SVC instance
Return the data transformed by a callable kernel
```

I'm not sure what that last bit means, because a kernel is an inner product of the transformed data, not the transformation of the data. Also, it appears to compute the identity mapping on examples I give it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to use the actual implementation of the kernel in SVC, because the kernel is computed lazily by libsvm under the hood for efficiency reasons. The function that you are trying to access is private (there is a leading underscore) and meant for internal use only.
If you want to compute the RBF kernel, you can simply call the [rbf_kernel](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.rbf_kernel.html#sklearn.metrics.pairwise.rbf_kernel) function.
The expensive part of the RBF kernel is the euclidean distance computation, which can be done efficiently with BLAS.
The reason while the SVM implementation is even faster, is because it never computes the whole kernel matrix, only the necessary parts.

Comment: The stable doc's link is [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.rbf_kernel.html#sklearn.metrics.pairwise.rbf_kernel)